# Stress-energy tensor definiton for scalar fields extension

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider the Stress-Energy-Momentum  tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$. The definition of $T_{\mu\nu}$ is given by $$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}_m}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}+g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_m,$$ where the $\delta$-derivative is the functional derivative with respect to the metric and $\mathcal{L}_m$ is the "matter Lagrangian density" and $-g=\det(g_{\mu\nu})$. Now consider some scalar field $\phi$  with its lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_m=-\frac12 \partial_{\alpha}\phi \partial^{\alpha}\phi-V(\phi)$. Now consider its Stress-Energy-Momentum tensor given by $$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}_m}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}=\partial_\mu\phi\partial_v\phi-\frac12g_{\mu\nu}(-\frac12 \partial_{\alpha}\phi \partial^{\alpha}\phi-V(\phi)).$$ Given this defintion of $T_{\mu\nu}$ , would it give me the result I am looking for in any specfic case? For example if I plug in values for the Matter lagrangian of a perfect fluid, or an anisotropic fluid, or dust even; Would I get the stress-energy tensor for those matter fields? Furthermore, could this defintion (if correct) be extended to any arbitrary matter field $\phi_a$ such that it would take the same form?

Comment: 1st expression is pretty general, however, sometimes the obtained stress energy tensor may not be symmetric in $\mu$ $\nu$ indices (eg. for Dirac field), so you have to do Belinfante Rosenfeld modifications (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belinfante%E2%80%93Rosenfeld_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor)

Comment: Alright, but does this defintion hold for any fluids or matter fields where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are symmetric?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681249/2451

Comment: You can only use this definition provided that the theory has a Lagrangian description. In general theory of relativity there is no additional assumption that the system needs to have a well defined $\mathcal{L}_m$. Anyhow, a Lagrangian description for fluids has been discussed here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0605010.pdf). You could also try to derive $T_{ab}$ from thermodynamic variables (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5278)